# How to parse data received through IPFS Python API

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, ipfs

I want to make a chatting room using Python based on IPFS.
I tried to use pubsub to send out and receive information.

```
import ipfsapi;
api=ipfsapi.connect("127.0.0.1",5001);
with api.pubsub_sub("topic",discover=True) as sub:
    for message in sub:
        print(message);
```

And data received looks like

```
{'from': 'EiDByeJhC7IHqQ2x2G+uGiFSSj1WUeNDp11qpwYDap5rNw==', 'data': 'dGVzdCBwdWIgbW9kZQ==', 'seqno': 'FYijZ/yJJXw=', 'topicIDs': ['topic']}
```

I don't know how to parse the source IPFS address and received data?

Answer (score 0):

That is `base64`, you need to decode it:

```
import base64
# This is and example of decoding your message['data']
coded_string = "dGVzdCBwdWIgbW9kZQ=="
base64.b64decode(coded_string)  # b'test pub mode'
```

Comment: I can't seem to find api.pubsub_sub() in the docs: https://ipfs.io/ipns/QmZ86ow1byeyhNRJEatWxGPJKcnQKG7s51MtbHdxxUddTH/Software/Python/ipfsapi/api_ref.html?highlight=ip#ipfsapi.Client. What is the class of your `message` object?

Comment: I find all the APIs here: https://github.com/ipfs/py-ipfs-api/blob/master/ipfsapi/client.py

Comment: message object is <class 'dict'>

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not familiar with `ipfsapi`, so I am a bit struggling to help you. When you mean the 'source IPFS', you mean the source ipfs of the message?

Comment: It looks from the docs that the 'from' contains the IPFS id, no? `'from': '<base64encoded IPFS id>'`

Comment: Yes! I just don't quite understand how to extract original string from encoded 'from'.

Comment: Just decode `message['from']`: `base64.b64decode(message['from'])`

Comment: base64.b64decode(message['from']).decode("utf-8") is better. It outputs Chinese characters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed regular Base64 encoded ([try with this online decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/)), but don't trip (as I did) over the decoding of the 'from' field, thinking that it can't be decoded. The result of the 'from' seems to be binary and will not decode into anything human readable (unless I'm mistaken). See also [this issue](https://github.com/ferristseng/rust-ipfs-api/issues/55) in the Rust client for comments from other struggling fellows.